# SFSafariViewController embedded in UISplitViewController doesn't refresh after collapsing using displayModeButtonItem

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller, sfsafariviewcontroller

I have a `SFSafariViewController` embedded in the detail panel of a `UISplitViewController` which is set to `UISplitViewControllerDisplayModeAllVisible`. This works perfectly well.

What I want to do is to be able to hide the master view. This works by sending a message to `displayModeButtonItem` (and it animates nicely), however the `SFSafariViewController` web view window doesn't refresh to take advantage of the new window size:

[image: SFSafariViewController screenshot]

If I push the application to the background - it does refresh to fill the window on return to the foreground.

I've tried the things that should work if the window contents were generated in-process (e.g. setting `needsLayout`). But I can't trigger a refresh.

I'm looking for suggestions that may work. However given the process isolation of the web view, it doesn't seem there is likely to be a solution that could be used in the app store :-)